# How to create multiple tables in jasper report using json as a datasource?

Tags: json, jasper-reports, subreport

I need to make report like this:

```
Product Name : Product XYZ

---------------------------------
| Item Name | Quantity | Price |
---------------------------------
| Item ABC  | 10       | 10 $  |
| Item BCD  | 10       | 1  $  |

Product Name : Product XYZ2

---------------------------------
| Item Name | Quantity | Price |
---------------------------------
| Item DEF  | 15       | 10 $  |
| Item HIJ  | 11       | 1  $  |

Summary Report 
---------------------------------
| Product Name | Total Quantity | 
---------------------------------
| Product XYZ  | 20             | 
| Product XYZ2 | 26             |
```

The first problem is "product" can 1 to many.

The second problem is i need "Summary Report" in the bottom

The third problem is ,this raw data report come from `json`, not from query to database.

What that i already try :

- Create many table for product. But this failed because jasper create empty space for unused table. And the summary table in other page with many empty space.
- Subreports , same like above.

Can you tell me please, how to make dynamically multiple table's?

**EDIT** : sample JSON

```
{"produkList": {
"items":[ 
    {
        "nameProduct": "Product XYZ",
        "itemList": [{
            "itemName": "XXXXXXX",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 50
        },
        {
            "itemName": "YYYYYYY",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 50
        },
        {
            "itemName": "ZZZZZZZZ",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 50
        }]
    },
    {
        "nameProduct": "Product XYZ2",
        "itemList": [{
            "itemName": "AAAAAAAA",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 50
        },
        {
            "itemName": "BBBBBBB",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 50
        },
        {
            "itemName": "CCCCCCC",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 50
        }]
    }
  ],
  "summary":[
  {
        "title": "Summary Report",
        "summaryReportDetailList": [{
            "nameProduct": "Product XYZ",
            "quantity": 150
        },
        {
            "nameProduct": "Product XYZ2",
            "quantity": 150
        }]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The structure will be

1. Main report with query `produkList.items` that display's **Product Name**
2. Subreport in `detail` band with `<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("itemList")]]></dataSourceExpression>` to display the **item table**
3. Subreport in `summary` band with query `produkList.summary.summaryReportDetailList` to display the **summary table**

**This is the result**

[image: PDF Result]

Below you will find the 3 jrxml producing this result, you need to adjust the path to the json source and path to subreport's, don't forget that subreport's need to be compiled in `.jasper` before main report can be run.

**Main report**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="multitable" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1c6dc1c9-67af-43d5-bf1e-9243557c8048">
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.source" value="C:/jdd/projects/StackTrace/jasper/multitable.json"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\jdd\\projects\\StackTrace\\jasper\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[produkList.items]]>
</queryString>
<field name="nameProduct" class="java.lang.String"/>
<detail>
    <band height="48" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="555" height="20" uuid="4dfdf5e5-436e-4538-b302-620ea945c6e7"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Product Name : " + $F{nameProduct}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="21" width="555" height="20" uuid="48a7bbe4-b8ce-4a0d-a6e1-6ddd288e5602"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("itemList")]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "multitable_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="52" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="555" height="32" uuid="780a1f25-065e-494a-ba1d-86a33b464343"/>
            <subreportParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.source">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA["C:/jdd/projects/StackTrace/jasper/multitable.json"]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "multitable_summary.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport in detail band** `multitable_subreport.jrxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="multitable_subreport" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="678bf408-397f-4797-bb50-84262b9df76b">
<field name="itemName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="price" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="af654b95-0a60-40fc-80c6-df38cc28061c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[itemName]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="7969463f-0569-4863-bbc3-a87364369a0f"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[quantity]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="86942d20-9a68-4409-8907-8abcfef1c82e"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[price]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="2b991eb1-6e24-4e74-8ee2-cd90fe07f60a"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{itemName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="###0.##">
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="71929061-2351-477c-8d2d-431c846f8a06"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
            <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="16b99246-d1f5-4c96-90db-34ea5f3141db"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport in summary band** `multitable_summary.jrxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="multitable_summary" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="2a869c20-1e7d-4baa-92d7-c8d555f1f344">
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[produkList.summary.summaryReportDetailList]]>
</queryString>
<field name="nameProduct" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="23">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="a9730039-8418-4e58-a2eb-0babe8d2a380"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Summary Report]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="a49b18ef-63c3-42bb-ae81-8d7d72ac9086"/>
            <box leftPadding="0">
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Product Name]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="c1c70fed-d887-429f-a3b0-ed645517e41f"/>
            <box leftPadding="0">
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[quantity]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="401436b3-d9a1-40bd-8a1d-dfa3f162f842"/>
            <box leftPadding="0">
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nameProduct}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="###0">
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4447d3b0-6d3e-4795-8b5f-6a09d620448b"/>
            <box leftPadding="0">
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: hai Peter, i try your example, but i get this error


net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("itemList")



Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource

Comment: Your are passing an EmptyDataSource during the fill process, don't pass any data source to the report. (JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, paramMap);)  (the datasource is define within the main.jrxml ... see <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.source"

Comment: You are great, man!! I tried and it worked =) and if anyone is having problem with this you can try "<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{addresses})]]></dataSourceExpression>", just like this post https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/533552/solved-problem-passing-datasource-subreport