# JsonDataSource for table fields get empty Jasper report

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I am new to jasper reports.
I am trying to generate a pdf from a son file, which contains some info like `name`, `class` etc and an array `marks`. I am trying to render the marks array as a table. my JSON is

```
{"data": {"name" : "Johny",
    "class" : "A2",
    "sub" : "cs",
    "interest" : "films",
    "marks" : [{
               "subject" : "Maths",
               "mark" : "24",
               "grade" : "A",
               "remarks" : "",
               "slNo" : "1"
               },
               {
               "subject" : "English",
               "mark" : "24",
               "grade" : "A",
               "remarks" : "",
               "slNo" : "2"
               },

               ]
}}
```

I have given subdatasource expression as

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Full jrxml - [Here](https://pastebin.com/gBddZr0R)

Now I call these from java like,

```
File jsonFile = new File("/Volumes/Johny/Work/EclipseWorkspace/SecondReport/res/Marks.Json");
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(new File("/Volumes/Johny/Work/EclipseWorkspace/SecondReport/res/First.jrxml"));
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

parameters.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, new FileInputStream(jsonFile));
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "/Users/johnykutty/Desktop/Sample2.pdf");
```

Other fields are getting populated, but table values are getting as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603844/how-to-create-multiple-tables-in-jasper-report-using-json-as-a-datasource#answer-34613614)
The issue was I have to pass the key for the array in `dataSourceExpression`. So, the `dataSourceExpression` should be like

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("marks")]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Note the "marks" parameter to `subDataSource()` method