# Using the same json datasource at several jr:table components

Tags: json, jasper-reports, dataset

I want to create 3 tables (in single report) from single *json* based dataset.

I'm able to create one table but while creating another I'm not sure what to use in datasource connection

For creating the first table I have used `$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}` as datasource connection while binding dataset to table, but for second and third tables I'm not sure how to bind that single dataset with all 3 tables

consider below json:

```
[
  { 
    "name": "HSBC Mandatory Provident Fund - SuperTrust",
    "Type of Transfer-in Accounts": "PA",
    "1": 5,
    "2": 5,
    "3": 5,
    "4": 5,
    "5": 5,
    "6": 5,
    "7": 5,
    "8": 5,
    "9": 5,
    "10": 5,
    "11": 5,
    "12": 5,
    "13": 5,
    "14": 5,
    "15": 5,
    ">7": 5,
    "total": 35}
]
```

expected output:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWd1A.png)

now below this table i want to create another table but instead of 1 to 7 days i want to show data of 8 to 15 from json thats it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple tables in jasper report using json as a datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603844/how-to-create-multiple-tables-in-jasper-report-using-json-as-a-datasource), it's very close to your example, the key is to *subDataSource*, your question does not have desired ouput, so better then this is hard to give you.

Comment: what if i dont want to use subreport, the option that u suggested is having sub report.i just want to use single data source and create tables in single report, lets say in one table i want to use 5 column of that json source and in another table i want to use 10 column of that json source kind of

Comment: same stuff, just replace the subreport with the jr:table component, both subreport and jr:table can take a "sub" datasource.

Comment: I have tried but it is not showing anything

Comment: Can you show the expected output, your current json does not seem very adapt to have subdatasource it has no array structure for the data of the different names.

Comment: i have edited the question,attached picture is what i am displaying right now,i want to create another table within the same report but with different field that will come from json(as of now i have put only one object in json for understanding,but in real multiple object will come in same format).so lets say in first table i have picked up 7 field from json and displayed it to one table and in another table i want another 7 field to be displayed using the same datasource and i am using simple json structure that is the reason i want to avoid subreport

Comment: Your json is not very well fit to do what you like, the only method I can see is to clean your datasource and then add the 2 table's each with a different datasource. The other solution is to change the json to be more adapt for this kind of visualizzation

Comment: i have tried creating 2 datasets with the same json file,and then bind it with table,but then it is only populating first table.second table showing null values..i have used $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} while binding table to dataser..i hope u got my question what i want to do?

Comment: If you pass from java pass the 2 datasource in 2 different parameters