# How to access value of field from another data source (JSON) in JasperReports?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I'm using TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.3.1 final. I'm trying to create a report using two datasources (the format is JSON).

The structure of JSON is like:

```
{    
    "first":
        {"parameter1" : 123},
    "second":[
        {"key" : 1},
        {"key" : 2}
    ]
}
```

So I have two datasources. One for the *first* object (firstSource) and another (secondSource) for *second* object (array of objects).

The array (*second*) is printed in the table component. I'd like to access a field from *first* object (first.parameter1) and print it in the table header.

The table is using this dataset:

```
<datasetRun uuid="4ee63b06-f4ee-45b4-9da8-3dabc3e7a09d">
    <dataSourceExpression> <![CDATA[$P{secondSource})]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

Then I'm printing its fields using `$F{key}`.

Do you know how can I access the *parameter1* of the *first* object from table? Maybe using some sort of $V{} variable or merging both datasources?

I tried to use subDataSource and subDataSet approach without any luck.

Here's something I'd like to achieve in the result table:

[image: result table]

Comment: It depends on the role of the first dataset. If you only use it for this, I would put the `first.parameter1` as a report parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with saying that json structure that you have in question is not the best structure to dynamically handle your expected output, it would have been better if `parameter1` was actually inside the second node, see this [How to create multiple tables in jasper report using json as a datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603844/how-to-create-multiple-tables-in-jasper-report-using-json-as-a-datasource) for how you could have handled and access the nodes if this was the case.

*Anyway*

Yes you are right in jasper reports you should think by datasource. In your expected output you basically have 2 datasources `second` which is your table and `first` which is your header. Yes first is only 1 record but to access it you can create a datasource for it and then use a component or a subreport to display it.

Considering this, one solution to your problem would be

1. Create a dataset for the table (field is `key`), passing as datasource the `second` node
2. Create a dataset for the header (field is `parameter1`), use this dataset in table to show the value.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="json_access_var" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="80e30745-0db9-476f-8bbb-cbc60d1ca90f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JsonTest2"/>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="DatasetMain" uuid="7918eaef-d2f7-4cdd-9b84-e2660b2bfed8">
        <parameter name="mainDatasource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource"/>
        <queryString language="JSON">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="key" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[key]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="DatasetTitle" uuid="7918eaef-d2f7-4cdd-9b84-e2660b2bfed8">
        <queryString language="JSON">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="parameter1" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[parameter1]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="JSON_INPUT_STREAM" class="java.io.InputStream" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <summary>
        <band height="260" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="60" uuid="40093b50-bd8d-4d56-8d1d-9f2e9cf86106">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetMain" uuid="0247b2fb-527b-4dc2-af7f-9bcd75e8715a">
                        <datasetParameter name="mainDatasource">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("second")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="25910003-959c-4e31-a91e-555e4aaf0bec">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <componentElement>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="da5b13da-671f-4eb6-bbf1-e455b293e4ce"/>
                                <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetTitle" uuid="d0a6bf94-cec6-4a75-96ec-4ae046ee90cc">
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{mainDatasource}).subDataSource("first")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="200">
                                        <textField>
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="2cd239b8-93ac-4cd2-82eb-f22db96dd010"/>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{parameter1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:listContents>
                                </jr:list>
                            </componentElement>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="24b2ba9b-57d0-4840-8333-70247f595e21"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{key}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Notes:**

1. In `DatasetMain` I create a parameter so I can access the report main datasource (the whole json file) again this time inside the table and create the new `subDataSource` for `first`
2. In the header I use a `jr:list` component to display the value of my second datasource (`parameter1`), you could also use a simple subreport to extract this value.

**Output** (using json provided in question)

[image: Result]